# SwiftUI: How can i customize the position of a geographic region in MapKit?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit

In my SwiftUI App, i have a MapView like this:

```swift
struct MapView: View {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
    
    var body: some View {
        Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
            .onAppear {
                setRegion(coordinate)
            }
    }
    
    private func setRegion(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        region = MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: coordinate,
            span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)
        )
    }
}
```

I am using this MapView like this:

```
MapView(coordinate: coordinate)
   .frame(height: 300)
```

[image]

I would like to change the position of the map, so London is no longer centered as the following picture shows:

[image]

But how can i do that? The function `MKCoordinateRegion` center the region, that i provide. So how can i change the position? Sorry i don't find any useful ressources about it.

Answer (score -1):

you could try something like this with `withAnimation`, works for me:
(because `coordinateRegion` is an animatable parameter of the view)

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreLocation


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var london = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.5, longitude: -0.1167)
    
    var body: some View {
        MapView(coordinate: london)
    }
}

struct MapView: View {
    @State var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    @State var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.56, longitude: -0.1167)
                setRegion(coordinate)
            }) {
                Text("Change map centre")
            }
            Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
        }
        .onAppear {
            setRegion(coordinate)
        }
    }
    
    private func setRegion(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        withAnimation {
            region.center = coordinate
            region.span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)
    // or
    //      region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2))
        }
    }
}
```